# NextJS `npm build` fails w/ app router and params/searchParams

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am using NextJS 14 with app router. My `npm build` fails on my Page:

```js
export default async function Page({ params, searchParams }) {
  ...
}
```

Error:

> Type error: Page "app/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
> Type "GetServerSidePropsContext" is not valid.

Running `npm run build` works just fine without errors.